# A4988 Jitter on stepper motor, some of the time

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper, a4988

Hardware:

- Arduino Uno Rev3
- A4988 Driver
- [Nema 8 Stepper](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-8-stepper-motor-bipolar-l-38mm-w-gear-ratio-5-1-planetary-gearbox-8hs15-0604s-pg5)

Setup:
I've adjusted the VRef of the driver based on the formula VRef = Imot * 8 * Rsen. With the values of Imot = .5 (max = .6), Rsen = .068.
A 12-Volt power supply is being used to supply power to the breadboard hat for the Arduino.

The Arduino code is being activated by a Python GUI, that is sending commands to the Arduino to make adjustments to the code in order to manipulate delay between steps, step size, and enable/disable. here is a simplified version of the Arduino code.

```
#include "src/Laser_Welder_8124.h"

void setup() {
    // 
    Serial.begin(115200);

    pinMode(STEPPER_DIR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(STEPPER_STEP, OUTPUT);
   
    pinMode(STEPPER_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(STEPPER_MS1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(STEPPER_MS2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(STEPPER_MS3, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS3, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(STEPPER_DIR, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_ENABLE, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    
    curMillis = millis();
    commsCheck();
    singleStep();
}

void commsCheck(){

    if(Serial.available() > 0){
        
        int rlen = Serial.readBytes(incomingMsg, MSGSIZE);
        byte cmd = incomingMsg[CMD_POS];

        int val = incomingMsg[VAL_POS];

        switch(cmd){
            case 0xC0:{
                enableStepperMotor(val);
                break;
            }
            case 0xC1:{

                toggleStepperDirection(cmdLookup[2].pin, val);
                break;
            }
            case 0xC2:{

                cmdLookup[0].state = val;
                millisBetweenSteps = val;
            
                break;
            }
            case 0xC7:{

                setStepSize(val);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void setStepSize(int val){

    switch(val){
        case 0xD0:{
            stepSize(HIGH, HIGH, HIGH);
            break;
        }
        case 0xD1:{
            stepSize(HIGH, HIGH, LOW);
            break;
        }
        case 0xD2:{
            stepSize(LOW, HIGH, LOW);
            break;
        }
        case 0xD3:{
            stepSize(HIGH, LOW, LOW);
            break;
        }
        case 0xD4:{
            stepSize(LOW, LOW, LOW);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void stepSize(int MS1, int MS2, int MS3){
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS1, MS1);
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS2, MS2);
    digitalWrite(STEPPER_MS3, MS3);
}

void toggleStepperDirection(int pin, int val)
{

    if (val == 0){
        cmdLookup[1].state = CW;
        digitalWrite(STEPPER_DIR, LOW);
    }
    else{
        cmdLookup[1].state = CCW;
        digitalWrite(STEPPER_DIR, HIGH);
    }
}

void singleStep() {

    if (curMillis - prevStepMillis >= millisBetweenSteps) {

        prevStepMillis = curMillis;
        digitalWrite(STEPPER_STEP, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(STEPPER_STEP, LOW);
    }
}
```

This works, for the most part.

I'm using the GUI to pass a value from 1-255 to represent a delay between steps in milliseconds.

If I set the time between steps to 1 ms, then it runs smoothly on all step sizes. However, when I start to play with the time delay, I get all sorts of jitter, at different time delays with different step sizes. How do I go about smoothing out the motor so I can use a range of delays across different step sizes?

I've attached a video link to show you what I'm seeing.

[Video Link of motor behavior](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ak_Up0H34vXskOYQQlwNglPhSoeHgg?e=xkX9yd)